# How to use a ArrayMap randomly

Tags: android, libgdx, array-map

I wrote the following ArrayMap:

```
ArrayMap<Sprite,String> arrayMap = new ArrayMap<Sprite, String>();
        arrayMap.put(sprite, "Rot");
        arrayMap.put(sprite1, "Braun");
        arrayMap.put(sprite2, "Dunkelblau");
        arrayMap.put(sprite3, "Dunkelgrün");
        arrayMap.put(sprite4, "Gelb");
        arrayMap.put(sprite5, "Hellblau");
        arrayMap.put(sprite6, "Hellgrün");
        arrayMap.put(sprite7, "Lila");
        arrayMap.put(sprite8, "Orange");
        arrayMap.put(sprite9, "Rosa");
```

Now I want to show randomly four of these sprites on a screen of a device. However, I don´t know how to use the ArrayMap and decide (randomly) which sprites will be drawn. I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About when to use [ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html) according to android documentation:

> Note that this implementation is not intended to be appropriate for
>   data structures that may contain large numbers of items. It is
>   generally slower than a traditional HashMap, since lookups require a
>   binary search and adds and removes require inserting and deleting
>   entries in the array. For containers holding up to hundreds of items,
>   the performance difference is not significant, less than 50%.

Using `Collections.shuffle()`:

```
    ArrayList<Sprite> keys = new ArrayList(arrayMap.keySet());
    Collections.shuffle(keys);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Sprite key = keys.get(i);
        String value = arrayMap.get(key);
    }
```

Comment: If I type that in, keySet is red. Error Message: "Cannot resolve method ´keySet()´.

Comment: I suspect you're using a LibGDX `ArrayMap` rather than the Android one: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ArrayMap.html. In which case, instead of `arrayMap.keySet()` use `arrayMap.keys()`

Answer (score 0):

try this code below

```
Random rand = something
int randIndex = rand.nextInt(list.size());
K key = list.get(randIndex);
V value = map.get(key);
```